# We flip 100 fair coins 6 times each, how many coins will end up being heads all 6 times or tails all six times?

Tags: statistics

I've solved for a single coin flipped 6 times and the probability that we get 6 flips as all heads or tails as 1/64 --> 1.56%

But I'm stuck on where to go from there.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binomial probability that a given fair coin will be only heads in 6 trials, or only tails in 6 trials, is $2^{-6}$.  The probability that in 6 trials it is only heads or only talks is thus $2^{-5}$.

If 100 fair coins are flipped 6 times each, the expected number that come up only heads or only tails is therefore $100 \times 2^{-5}=3.125$.

This is equivalent to a non-rounded version of one of the solution proposed by @DontWorry: after 1 roll, you expect $100/2$ coins to be only heads; after 2 rolls, the expectation is $100/2^2$, and after 6 rolls, the expectation is $100/2^6$, so for both only heads or only tails, the expected number is $100/2^5$.

Comment: This is great, thank you!